# Xcode 11 and iOS 13 Modal ViewController lost black overlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I have a `UIViewController A` which presents modally another `UIViewController B` which takes up only the bottom half the screen height.

Back when I was still using Xcode 10, when the modal ViewController B is presented, a dark overlay will cover ViewController A and I will also set the view.alpha of ViewController A to 0.5 using these methods:

```
func presentBottomSheet() {

  let viewController = BottomSheetModalVC()
  viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.dimParent()
        self?.parentViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

func dimParent() {
 UIView.transition(with: parentVC.view, duration: 0.6, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
   parentVC.view.alpha = 0.5
 })
}
```

in order to shift the user's focus to the modal view. However, when I tried to compile this with Xcode 11, the black overlay is done and I am left with a parent view who only becomes half visible when the modal view slides up from the bottom. Was there a change in this overlay behaviour?

My screen looks something similar to this. But after Xcode 11, the black overlay is no longer there leaving me with a completely transparent overlay. [image]

Comment: you need to use full screen

Comment: I used .fullScreen to display ViewController B but since the it is only half the height of my screen, users are still able to "peek through" ViewController A'S contents as the bottom sheet emerges.

Comment: remove this line viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

Comment: It didn't work. @iOS_MIB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer to this silly question.

So it turns out that the UINavigationController presenting ViewController A & B had its background color set to white so when ViewController A has its alpha set to 0.5, it just looks like it was disappearing but not dimming.

I have set my NavigationController background color to black now and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView in ViewControllerB. In your case its BottomSheetModalVC

```
var backgroundView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    return view
}()
```

Add the backgroundView as a subView to the presentingViewController's view

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    presentingViewController?.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    backgroundView.frame = presentingViewController?.view.bounds ?? .zero
}
```

Remove this backgroundView in viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
           self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
       }
}
```

Comment: This was something that I was looking that as an interim solution but still it doesn't really explain what changed between XCode 10 and XCode 11 which caused this to happen.